# Grav, get pages by taxonomy - page.url not working

Tags: twig, grav

In Grav which uses twig as a templating engine, I have:

```
<ul>
    {% for page in taxonomy.findTaxonomy({'tag': 'shell'}) %}
        <li><a href="{{ page.url }}">{{ page.title }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}

</ul>
```

to get all pages that have `tag` set to `shell` -

However, `page.title` renders fine, but `page.url` gives
`%7B%7B%20page.url%20%7D%7D`?

If I put `page.url` in place where `page.title` is, so between `<a></a>` tags,
everything works fine? Is this some kind of bug?

**EDIT**

Exactly the same as described here: https://github.com/erusev/parsedown/issues/266

**FOUND SOLUTION**

Luckily `Grav` has an option to process twig first then markdown.

By setting `twig_first: true` into page meta, I was able to solve the problem.

So the culprit is markdown processor.

Comment: You solution worked for me too. However, please post your found solution as an actual answer, so that me and others might accept it. This is how things work around here.

Answer (score 1):

just print the object using `{{var_dump(page)}}`
then you can see the getter method or array value of the object.

Here is my solution for your problem `{{ page.route }}`

It is working for me!

Hope this helps someone.